# Function which changes a dataframe inplace used to slices of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Suppose I have a function which takes as input a dataframe d and which
alters the dataframe **inplace**. In the example below the function writes the number 9 to the first two rows.

Suppose I wanted to use the same function to achieve the following:
(a) write 9 to the first two rows - but only to the "x" column
(b) write 9 to the second and third rows

In each case, I would find it very convenient if I could just pass an appropriate slice
to the function, e.g. in case (a) call the function with d.loc[,["x"]] instead of using the whole dataframe.

However, I noticed that the function will not change the original dataframe. (see below)

My question: How can I modify the code within the function to achieve this goal? Note that I don't want to create copies of the dataframe (every change should be inplace) and note that I do not want to expand the function signature.

```
import pandas as pd

#toy dataframe with two columns
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,3,4,5], "y": [4,3,2,3]})

# This function changes the first two rows of the input dataframe inplace
def change(d):
    n = len(d)
    d.loc[[True, True] + [False]*(n-2)] = 9
    return d

change(df)
df # df has changed

#Recreate the original df
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,3,4,5], "y": [4,3,2,3]})
# Create a reference to a portion of df
df_ref = df.loc[:,["x"]]
# Call change with the reference
change(df_ref)
df # has not changed
```

**EDIT**

For clarification:
I just ask the following: If a function uses as input a dataframe and changes this dataframe inplace, how can I ensure that it also works on parts of the dataframe? (that is, I do not provide the dataframe as an argument, but only a subset of rows/columns as the argument). And by "works" I mean that although I provided only a subset of rows/columns it changed the original dataframe in the respective rows/columns.

Comment: That's not possible, `df_ref` is not a reference/view to `df`, it is an independent copy. You can check that `df_ref` **has changed**.

Comment: `df_ref` and `df` are two different dataframes.

Comment: Ok, but how can I create a reference instead of a copy - so that the function works as intended?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Please see my edit. I think it is a very common task I ask to achieve

Comment: Given your edit, what you want is impossible, you cannot be sure that what you pass is a reference or a copy to the original DataFrame. IMO, this is doomed to fail and will lead to bugs. Here you're explaining the X of the XY problem, we need to know the Y.

Comment: Also, why the need to modify "in place"? This is a common misconception that this is *faster/more efficient*. Better have a function that outputs a modified slice and reassign it to the original DataFrame explicitly.

Comment: I find it striking to believe that copying a potentially large dataframe is efficient if I only want to modify a tiny portion of data within it.

Comment: @P.Jo but you **can** modify a tiny portion efficiently by assigning the values. In your shown example, you would need to directly assign 9 to the first two rows of the selected columns: `df.loc[df.index[:2], 'x'] = 9`. No need for a function. This is the most efficient. Thus your true use case remains unclear and I really believe that what you need to do is **clearly explain what you're really trying to do, without relying on an abstract function and your idea of using named slices of your dataframe**.

Comment: In the example you gave: Ofc I can do this. But this only works because (a) the logic is simple and (b) I no the use case in advance. My question refers to using a function (which might be written by someone else and which might encapsulate some difficult logic) and to the goal of applying that function inplace to a portion of my data

Comment: I'm sorry but without more details this question most likely won't have a useful answer. I'm voting to close the question.